# How to link another html page in Spring Boot Thymeleaf Template Engine?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have following Spring Boot project structure (using Thymeleaf) -

[image]

Now, when I tried to reference `defect-details.html` from `index.html` it could not be found. I tried all the following options to no avail:

1.`<a th:href="@{/defect-details.html}">`

2.`<a th:href="@{defect-details.html}">`

3.`<a href="defect-details.html">`

Every time it says `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)`.

Please help to find the issue.

Comment: The whole point of the MVC architecture is to always send requests to controllers, which then dispatch to views. Linking to other views isa big no-no.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for pointing that out. I have modified the controller now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(As **JBNizet** pointed out in the comment) As per MVC design architecture it's better to use controller to render the views instead of view-to-view links. All I had to do was update my Controller class with:

```
@RequestMapping("/defect-details")
public String defectDetails() {
    return "defect-details";
}
```

And in the Thymeleaf template:

```
<a th:href="@{defect-details}">
```

Comment: Can you explain me, what exactly happens when we use controller to render the views instead of view-to-view links?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use HTML  tag to link two pages in Thymeleaf,
However you wont be able to go to a specific HTML page from one HTML page directly without going through spring controller first. You have to make a request to Spring Controller to get that page for you. In order to get it done :--

1.)    `<a href="defect-details.html">  //on your index.html`

2.)  Get this request on your Spring Controller to open defect-details.html page for you :--

```
@RequestMapping("/defect-details")
public String defectDetails() {
    return "defect-details"; //defect-details.html page name to open it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ModelAndView` class also:

```
@RequestMapping("/defect-details")
public ModelAndView defect-details(){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("defect-details");
    return mv;
}
```